# WinRT Xaml Toolkit Bar Chart error?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Whenever I use a chart with a Line series of column series (any series other than Pie Series), I have this error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture. Make sure
>   WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Properties.Resources.resources
>   was correctly embedded or linked into assembly
>   "WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization" at compile time, or that
>   all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed

what can be wrong here ?

here's the XAML:

```
<charting:Chart Name="columnChart"  Grid.Row="1"  Width="400" Height="400"   >
                            <charting:Chart.Series>
                                <charting:ColumnSeries  ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                             IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
                        IsSelectionEnabled="True">

                                </charting:ColumnSeries>
                            </charting:Chart.Series>
                        </charting:Chart>
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in NuGet packaging. Are you using it with NuGet?

Comment: Yes, I added reference to the toolkit with NuGet, is there any workaround ?

Comment: You can simply download the [source code](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7f8d41517cbe) and add the project to your solution. I'll see if I can find a moment tonight to look into fixing the NuGet package, but for now - the workaround should work perfectly.

Comment: I updated the toolkit on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit) and [CodePlex](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/99868) but I don't think I changed anything related to your issue. I tested the NuGet package and it seemed to work fine. Could you share a sample project? Also - are you using your Windows with non-English-US locale? I never had a chance to test it with different locales and there is no localization code that I am aware of. Perhaps I do miss a default locale setting somewhere in the project.

Comment: I removed the references and added them again with NuGet, the error disappeared, but can't navigate to the page, it throws some exception, I updated the question with the source

Comment: I see the same problem described above, my machine is set to en-AU culture and it bombs at:
WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Properties.Resources.get_Series_OnGlobalSeriesIndexPropertyChanged_UntitledSeriesFormatString()

Forcing en-US culture doesn't seem to help and either does building from the source code vs using the nuget package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK
removing the references and adding again using NuGet solved the initial problem, the solution to the Column Chart in this link [WinRT Xaml Toolkit Column Series Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596813/winrt-xaml-toolkit-column-series-error)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Adding the source to my own solution did not help by itself. I did manage to fix it by changing the Build Action of the resources file to Embedded Resource.