# WinRT Xaml Toolkit Column Series Error?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I have a Chart from [Win RT Xaml Toolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) that I want to display a ColumnSeries like this:

```
<charting:Chart Name="columnChart" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="400" Height="400">
    <charting:Chart.Series>
        <charting:ColumnSeries  
             ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
             IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
             DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" 
             IsSelectionEnabled="True">
        </charting:ColumnSeries>  
    </charting:Chart.Series>
</charting:Chart>
```

but I always receive this error:

> WinRT information: Cannot add instance of type
>   'WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.ColumnSeries' to
>   a collection of type 
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.ISeries>'

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I found it,

The error was the **ColumnSeries** was missing the **Title** attribute, like this:

```
<charting:Chart Name="columnChart" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="400" Height="400">
    <charting:Chart.Series>
        <charting:ColumnSeries  
             Title="Chart Title"
             ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
             IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
             DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" 
             IsSelectionEnabled="True">
        </charting:ColumnSeries>  
    </charting:Chart.Series>
</charting:Chart>
```

It seems that the **Title** attribute is mandatory.

Comment: I am finding I constantly get Errors such as A value of type 'BarSeries' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'Collection`1' which is v similar. (Using win 8.1 and v 1.6.0.5) Adding Title doesn't help.

Comment: For some reason adding `Title` worked... I also forgot to put <charting:ColumnSeries>` into a  `<charting:Chart.Series>`

Comment: Just so that people know, this solution also works for the **LineSeries**, which presents the same problem when used without the **Title** property.